# How to factorize this equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

$$\frac{(x^2+1)^2(-2x)-(-x^2+1)(4x^3+4x)}{(x^2+1)^4} = 0$$

I am having trouble factorizing this equation such that the solutions are  $\sqrt3$,0

I try expanding the terms in the numerator and then expanding the denominator but this did not work out

$$\frac{2x^5-4x^3-6x}{(x^2+1)^4}$$
$$2x^5-4x^3-6x  = x^8+4x^6+10x^2+1$$

Comment: First, what is $4x^3+4x$ factorised?

Comment: $$2(x^2+1)2x$$.

Comment: $-\sqrt3$ should also be a solution, so the solutions are $\pm\sqrt3$ and $0$.

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts, you should show what you tried in your question, otherwise your question will be closed very soon and  the account of the user who has answered your question will be suspended.

Comment: @Angelo Suspension seems rather harsh.

Comment: It would help to check if the terms in the numerator have common factors before you try to simplify the numerator.

Comment: Is your goal trying to "factorize this equation"? To factorise the LHS numerator, you may see that $(x^2+1)2x$ is a common factor of the numerator terms.

Comment: @Angelo I think you're being a bit overbearing. I'm not sure I'd call this a truly low-quality question. That said: OP: did you intend the RHS to be $0$? If so, you can ignore the denominator completely ($\forall x \in \mathbb{R}: x^2+1 \ne 0 $), making this as simple as factoring $x(2x^4-4x^2-6)$, which is quadratic in $x^2$ and factors easily. Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the numerator:
$$(x^2+1)^2(-2x)-(-x^2+1)(4x(x^2+1))=(x^2+1)(-2x(x^2+1)-(4x(-x^2+1)))=(x^2+1)(2x^3-6x)$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: should I expend the denominator?

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts No, why would you do that? Also add what you have tried to your question

Comment: @bb_823 can´t take it from there

Comment: cant find the answer $\sqrt{3}$,$-\sqrt{3}$

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts $(2x^3-6x)=2x(x^2-3)=2x(x-\sqrt{3})(x+\sqrt{3})$

Comment: thank you ......